# 405 Method not Allowed, PATCH not working. Laravel, Ajax, Jquery, bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

In laravel i have a 405 error, butt the strange thing is that when i want to edit some data and click on Update it don't refresh or load the page. when i refresh the page myself the update is set! only i get a error 405 PATCH method not allowed. i have doing some searching on the internet butt can't find how to solve this. things that i have found was like check your apache2 config, add csrf field, make form action post and put {!! method_field('patch') !!} inside that.
i have try al lot of things.

someone that can help me with this issue!
Thanks al lot

My Route for the project:

```
Route::resource('project', 'ProjectViewController');
```

My Controller for the project

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{ DB::table('projects')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->update($request->all()); return redirect('')->with('success', 'Project has been updated'); 

}
```

My Jquery Ajax :

```
$('.modal-footer').on('click', '.edit', function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'PATCH',
        url: '{{route('project.update', $project->id)}}',
        data: {
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            'id': $('#fid').val(),
            'project_name': $("#pn").val(),
            'date': $('#Da').val(),
            'location': $('#Lo').val(),
            'first_name': $('#FN').val(),
            'last_name': $('#LN').val(),
            'city_name': $('#CN').val(),
            'email': $('#EM').val(),
            'number': $('#NUM').val()
        },
        success: function(data){if(data.success == true){ // if true (1)
  setTimeout(function(){// wait for 5 secs(2)
       location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
  }, 2000); }},
```

Comment: instead of `method: 'PATCH',` use `method: 'PUT',`

Comment: instead of `method: 'PATCH'`, use `type: 'PATCH'` or `type: 'PUT'`!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this what i get in the network tab: message "The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."                     this is also when i do PATCH

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `POST` as method and you need to define `_method=post` your sended data. Please try the following code.

`$('.modal-footer').on('click', '.edit', function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '{{route('project.update', $project->id)}}',
        data: {
            '_method': 'PUT',
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            'id': $('#fid').val(),
            'project_name': $("#pn").val(),
            'date': $('#Da').val(),
            'location': $('#Lo').val(),
            'first_name': $('#FN').val(),
            'last_name': $('#LN').val(),
            'city_name': $('#CN').val(),
            'email': $('#EM').val(),
            'number': $('#NUM').val()
        },
        success: function(data){if(data.success == true){ // if true (1)
  setTimeout(function(){// wait for 5 secs(2)
       location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
  }, 2000); }},`

Comment: thanks for the answer, only when i do this i get a sql state error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in 'field list'

Comment: You need to exclude `_method` while inserting data to DB. Can you send me code block where getting error, please ?

Comment: Thanks all for your comments its working now.